# Is there any code covergae tool for Windows Workflow 4.0?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Need to find out how to do code coverage for WF workflows and activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities deriving from CodeActivity and NativeActivity is simple, that is just regular C# code. As fas activities defined in XAML goes as well as the VB expressions in the workflows you are out of luck as far as I know.